# Is it good practice to create a separate table for views count?

Tags: mysql, database-design, best-practices, relations

I have created a `blog` table where I'm having a field called `views_count` but I have heard that updating the `views_count` field on each page view is strain. So I have created now a seperate table for views count as below:

```
views:
id,
blog_id,
ip_address,
counter
```

Now I'm storing unique visits in `views` table. And when I save record in view table I also update `blog` field `views_count` field, so is this a good approach? Or is there a better alternative?

Full Creates Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `video_blog` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `video_embed_code` text,
  `video_thumbnail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_thumbnail_alt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `views` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

-- Table structure for table `video_blog_category`

CREATE TABLE `video_blog_category` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_by` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

-- Table structure for table `video_blog_views_tracker`

CREATE TABLE `video_blog_views_tracker` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_blog_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_ip_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

**Note:** Our website blog is getting millions of visitors daily. So the new table will get updated frequently.

Comment: It is 'data override' and is a bad practice in common. The best way is do not store this data obtaining it by query `SELECT blog_id, SUM(counter) FROM views GROUP BY blog_id` when it needs. *And when I save record in view table I also update `blog` field `views_count` field* And what the difference - to update this field directly or with intermediate insert into `views`?

Comment: @Akina Actually I will fetch views count in each blog post, so it will be better to also store it in `blog` `views_count` field. Otherwise at each blog page i will be querying the `views` table which is an extra request. BUT i think both cost a request!

Comment: *I will fetch views count in each blog post* If so data override can be reasonable. Especially taking into account that a small inaccuracy of this data does not matter. Just additionally provide periodic execution of the procedure which recalculates this data.

Comment: @Akina Actually I'm creating new fresh blog functionality and I am also creating this counter in this. In our old functionality we are having a `blog` table and `blog_tracking` table which are causing performance issue. And the issue is because there are million of visitors each day and `blog_tracking` table is updated with each unique view. So i want a better solution to handle this issue in my rewrite.

Comment: I think that trigger logic with single-row update will not be too expensive...

Comment: @Akina even if there is million of visitors daily? Are you sure?

Comment: 1kk/day ~ 10/s.

Comment: The discussions are getting messy.  Please provide `CREATE TABLE` statements for proposed solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a mere 10 updates per second, this is a non-issue.

When you get to 100/sec, and are still using HDD, then we can discuss further.  Or 1000/sec with SDD.

At higher rates, yes, violate the textbook principles and have the view-counter in a separate table (with only the `count`, plus `page_id` as the PK `page_id`).  The reason is to avoid conflicts with non-counter accesses to the main table.

If you are keeping track of each 'view' as in a table of "who viewed what, when", the problem gets messier.  On the one hand, there are `INSERTs` into that table (again, 10/sec is not a problem).  On the other hand, `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` will have extremes -- a count of 100 is no problem, but a count of a million can be.

"Likes" have similar issues.

For more extreme traffic, you need to gather up the updates/inserts, consolidate them, then apply them.  This might get you another 10x speedup, at the expense of some complexity and a few seconds delay in updating the counters.

But, by that time, you will have outgrown a single server, and other solutions will be needed for all your problems.  Sharding is a likely part of this next level of design.

For any system that starts small, and grows to be huge, you *must* expect to do a major redesign every so often.  For you (today), moving the counters out is premature.  However, doing so could forestall (for a while) the next major redesign.

**Rehash**

**Plan A:**  (all in one)

```
CREATE TABLE Blog (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    lots of meta info -- title, etc
    view_ct INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**Plan B:**  (split out just the counter)

```
CREATE TABLE Blog (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    lots of meta info -- title, etc
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE BlogViews (
    blog_id INT UNSIGNED,   -- not A_I; for joining to Blog
    view_ct INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,   -- optional -- time of last viewing??
    PRIMARY KEY(blog_id)
);
```

Discussion of Plan A:

- Simpler
- Good enough for "low traffic" website -- say 10 views/sec.

Advantages of B:

- Needs `JOIN`, but only when both meta and count are needed together.  This `JOIN` is *NOT* a big burden.
- Updating the count hits *only* `BlogViews`, thereby not interfering with any queries that need *only* meta info, especially `UPDATEs` to such.
- Needed for busy website -- say peak loading of 1000 views/sec.

**When to use C:**

- Thousands of views/sec.
- C involves collecting views, consolidating them, *then* updating a structure like Plan B.
- This further isolates both `Blogs` and `BlogViews` from interference.
- View counts may be slightly delayed (seconds).
- (Further details can be discussed elsewhere)

**Plans A2, B2, C2, D2:**

- These are modifications to the other plans, wherein you keep track of 'who' views the blogs 'when'.
- This needs to worry about `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of merely `SELECT view_ct`.
- `SELECT COUNT(*)` can be costly if you have a million views.
- These extensions are best handled with "Summary Table" design concepts, which I cover [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

**Plan E** (Now that the actual schemas are presented, I'll call that E):

For `video_blog_views_tracker`, get rid of `id`, and have

```
PRIMARY KEY(video_blog_id, user_ip_address)  -- should be unique
```

That should be optimal for the counter query:

```
SELECT SUM(counter) FROM video_blog_views_tracker
    WHERE video_blog_id = ?
```

Yes, rolling that into `video_blog.views` via a `TRIGGER` or CRON job is *possible*.  But I would not do it until the need is determined.

Comment: I have created `blog_views_counter` table I have created `id`, `video_blog_id`, and `count` field. 

And in main `video_blog` table I have a field called `views_counter` for storing static value.

Now I'm using the separate table `blog_views_counter` for storing the new entries or updating old, and also I'm updating `views_counter` field in `video_blog`. And in main blog page I'm accessing total views from `video_blog` field `views_counter` field. How is this approach?

Comment: I'm not trying to argue that 1 million updates in a day isn't necessarily a lot... But I don't think it's safe to assume that 1 million/day = 11/second. Peak load (ex mid day for OP's core geographic market) may easily be 10x or more. Unsure of @DojoDev's needs, but it may be more appropriate to plan for that peak, rather than an average.

Comment: @AMtwo - Sure, peak loading is important.  I use the Rule of Thumb: "Under 100 QPS is probably not a problem".  11/sec * 10x ~= 100.

Comment: @DojoDev - There is (I think) no need for `id`; `video_blog_id` is a _better_ `PRIMARY KEY` for that counter table.  When will you copy the counter into `video_blog` table?  And why bother??  A simple `JOIN` let's you get the counter _in the few queries that need it_.

Comment: @RickJames Please check this snap. ( https://imgur.com/aRGcIww ) I'm following this approach. As i mentioned i will be having millions of hits daily so updating `video_blog` table isn't a good idea, so i just update the views table and the time i update the views table I will then update `video_blog` count field. Along with that I will be able to fetch `views` from `video_blog` without JOIN.

Comment: @DojoDev - I got lost in his use of "static value" and "unique".  What is in `video_blog`?  If it is just an id an count, then that is the most efficient way to keep the count.  If it as all the info about the blog, then the conflicts is what I am worried about.  I see no reason to update the same number in two places; that will be worse than the `JOIN`.

Comment: `video_blog` has all post data. i.e post title, description and post total views. So it will be easy to fetch all post related data from one table. Rather then using join for getting views! What you think?

Comment: At 10/sec, KISS -- Simply update the `video_blog.views` in real time; no extra table, no CRON, etc.  At 100/sec, no counter in that table, use `JOIN` _when you need the count_.  The update need hit only the counter table, which has 2 columns `PRIMARY KEY(video_blog_id)` and `count`.

Comment: @RickJames final question please, So if my visitors are in millions i should only use `views` table for accessing and updating count right? No need for `video_blog.views` update?

Comment: @DojoDev - oops; terminology mismatch.  I meant to refer to the table with one counter per video (or blog or whatever?).  (I work better with _all_ the relevant table presented in `CREATE TABLE` format.  Or, in this case, two sets of `CREATEs`, one with counters separate, one with them included in the main table(s).)

Comment: @DojoDev - And I am confused as to whether a "video" is a separate entity from a "blog", with separate meta info, counter, etc.

Comment: @DojoDev - OK, I'm "eating my own dogfood" -- I added a "rehash" to my Answer, complete with `CREATEs`.

Comment: @RickJames hey buddy question is updated with tables schema please suggest a better option now :)

Comment: @DojoDev - Is a row in `video_blog_views_tracker` saying "People at this IP address have watched this video N times."  I suggest that N is rarely more than 1, at least for adults.

Comment: @RickJames yes if we catch a person with same IP we increase the counter only.

Comment: @DojoDev - So, the total view-count for a specific video_blog involves `SELECT SUM(counter) FROM video_blog_views_tracker WHERE ...`  I'm sorry it has taken this much back-and-forth to understand the basic premise of your counting.  (It's perhaps not typical.)

Comment: @DojoDev - OK, I made your method "Plan E", and added comments about it.